# On the properties of Laplacian

Tags: operator-theory, laplacian

$$\Delta_{\mathbf{x}} :=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}, \qquad \mathbf{x}=(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
Suppose I want to make a *coordinate shift*, namely $\mathbf{x}\longmapsto\mathbf{y}:=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0$.
The claim is
$$\Delta_\mathbf{x}= \Delta_{\mathbf y}$$
Any hint on how to proceed?

Is it enough to say that every linear operator is invariant under shift?

Comment: Every _constant_ _coefficient_, linear operator is invariant under shifts, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{x}= \vec{y}+\vec{x_o}$

Where $\vec{x_o}$ is a constant vector, hence applying the chain rule we get:

$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$ =$\sum_{j} \dfrac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_i}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_j} = \sum_{j}\delta_{ij}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_j}= \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$

So actually any differential operator is invariant under shift, and hence in particular the Laplacian.

Comment: Be careful: the operators invariant under shifts typically must have constant coefficients, for example... :)

Comment: Yes, you're right of course.